# In Appcelerator Studio, how do I create new scopes?

Tags: themes, syntax-highlighting, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I’ve used Sublime Text for a few years, and its theming is based on TextMate, which Appcelerator Studio says *its* theming is also based on. In ST3, you build a syntax-highlighting theme in a `.tmTheme` file and you extend the pool of scope definitions in a `.tmLanguage` file.

I’d like to use the same syntax highlighting in both programs, but I can’t find out how to get Appcelerator Studio to see the same scopes as ST3.

Can someone point me to information that would help me solve this dilemma?

Comment: I can't give you a direct answer but since its based on Eclipse you can search for eclipse themes/syntax-highlighting too. It will give you more results and perhaps a quicker help

Comment: But  you can using Appc CLI + sublime Instead of Appc studio .